# Showing all values of a nested json using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, foreach, mapping

I am trying to show all the values of the JSON i have using lodash, which ive read that it is best suited in situations like this, the json is deep as you can see and some categories are empty which made it more challenging to me, i am wondering which function is most suitable to display such unstructured and deep JSON. is it foreach or filter? and is lodash the best option here? the data will eventually be displayed in a react app, but for now i am trying to do the mapping/foreach/filter or whatever it is that can go dynamically go through all the items.

Expected output is list items nested tree.

```
{

  "name": "Menu",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Burgers",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Coming Soon Offers"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Pizzas",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please tell expected output or part of it

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: List items <li> @Harish

Comment: List items <li> @MaheerAli

Comment: @AlxL Do you want to display a nested tree or just everything in `<li>`?

Comment: Display a nested tree

Comment: @AlxL I gave the answer see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have handle the data of unknown depth you should use recursion.

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Menu",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Burgers",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Coming Soon Offers"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Pizzas",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Promo 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
let body = document.querySelector('body');
function print(obj){
  let str = `<li>${obj.name}</li>`;
  if(obj.children){
    str += '<ul>' 
    for(let c of obj.children) str += print(c)
    str += '</ul>'
  }
  return str;
}
document.body.innerHTML = print(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way without lodash.

```js
const buildMenu = (data) => {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  data.children.forEach(i => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = i.name;
    li.className = i.type;
    if (i.children) li.appendChild(buildMenu(i));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });

  return ul;
};

let data = {

  "name": "Menu",
  "children": [{
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Burgers",
      "children": [{
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 1",
          "children": [{
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [{
                "type": "item",
                "name": "Promo 1"
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Burger 2",
          "children": [{
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [{
                "type": "item",
                "name": "Promo 1"
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Tomato"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Pickles"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Coming Soon Offers"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "category",
      "name": "Pizzas",
      "children": [{
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 1",
          "children": [{
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [{
                "type": "item",
                "name": "Promo 1"
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "Pizza 2",
          "children": [{
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Promo",
              "children": [{
                "type": "item",
                "name": "Promo 1"
              }]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "name": "Drinks",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Light Coke"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Sprite"
                },
                {
                  "type": "item",
                  "name": "Fanta"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "modifier",
              "name": "Without",
              "children": [{
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Onion"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Mashrooms"
                },
                {
                  "type": "ingredient",
                  "name": "Olives"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

document.body.appendChild(buildMenu(data));
```